# How could I update inner widget if list changes, and notify outer widget if inner widget changes?

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

I basically have a structure like this:

```
--OuterWidget
  --ListWidget
    --ListElementWidget1
    --ListElementWidget2
    ...
    --ListElementWidget3
```

WHat I wanna do is the following: whenever a user checks a checkbox in ListElementWidget, I want to be notified about that in OuterWidget. Also, whenever I add an element to the list in OuterWidget, I want that to be reflected in ListWidget.
I could do the simple method of passing down a notifier in constructor, but is there a simpler way?

Comment: Callback method may help. Can you provide sample widget that will reproduce the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Look at [stateful widgets](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html)

```dart
void onPressed() {
  setState(() {
    // Here you can set values in your widget 
    // and it will update all widgets in state.
  });
}
```

Sorry if code wrong I am typing from memory...
Full code example:

```dart
class Page extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State createState(BuildContext context) => _PageState();
}

class _PageState extends State<Page> {
  int someValue = 0; 

  Widget build() => TextButton(
    text: Text(someValue.toString()),
    onPress: () => SetState(() {
      someValue += 4;
    })
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the world of State Management!

The easiest way to know if a checkbox changed in `ListElementWidget` is passing a callback method down the chain, like you've already mentioned, then calling that when the user checks a checkbox.

```
OuterWidget() => ListWidget(toggleCheckCallBack) => ListElementWidget(toggleCheckCallBack);
```

And, for the updating of the `ListWidget`, simply making `OuterWidget` a [`StatefulWidget`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html) and calling [`setState`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html) when an element is added should resolve that too.

While this does solve the issue, it probably wouldn't scale well, if you believe this is a problem, take a look at the various [state management libraries](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options) Flutter has.

Comment: It wouldn't really be a problem in this project, but that is exactly what I wanted to avoid. Thank you anyways

Comment: You could take a look at the [Provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) package, it is easy to use and can help you avoid using callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

I uesd [flutter notification mechanism](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Notification-class.html)  solved my question.

for example:

```
class ContainerHeightChangedNotification extends Notification {
 final double changedHeight;

 ContainerHeightChangedNotification(this.changedHeight);
}
```

then,call dispatch when inner container height changed

```
ContainerHeightChangedNotification(
          widget.isFold ? 0 : widget.unfoldHeight - widget.foldHeight)
      .dispatch(context);
```

outer,you should wrap your child with

```
NotificationListener<ContainerHeightChangedNotification>(
  onNotification: (notification) {
    widget.height += notification.changedHeight;
    return true;
  },
  child: your child,
);
```

wish helps